# Radioactive satellite falls back to earth

Tags: story-identification, movie

I recall a black & white movie from the early 1960's or late 1950's about a satellite that fell back to earth and somehow got wedged in a cave or something similar.  When people came in contact with it, they got trapped in some sort of crystalline structure, essentially becoming part of the (radioactive?) satellite.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like "The Flame Barrier"(1958).
Here is the plot synopsis from Wikipedia.

"A woman comes to a small South American jungle village to seek the aid of a reclusive but highly experienced jungle guide, to find her husband who has disappeared while on an exploratory expedition of his own. The husband has specifically gone into the jungle to locate and retrieve an experimental earth satellite, which unexpectedly fell back to earth, out of control, after entering a part of the stratosphere known as the "flame barrier". The guide reluctantly agrees after much persuasion by the woman and also by his ne'er-do-well brother, both of whom accompany him on his trek. Eventually, the satellite is discovered in a cave near the husband's deserted campsite, and is found to be contaminated by an alien life-form which doubles its size every few hours. The problem then becomes one of saving the world."

I can't find any good videos or photos, but have included the IMDb page link below. If you read the 2nd and 3rd user review, you'll see it matches your description.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0051618/?ref_=nv_sr_1

Comment: That sounds like it!  You, my friend, are a rock star!  I will look for this, and if I find it someplace online, I will report back here with great glee and gusto.  Thank you, friend!